# Unable to dual-boot Windows 7 and Kubuntu 10.10

Tags: 10.10, dual-boot, windows-7, kubuntu

I have installed Windows 7 and Kubuntu 10.10, but the boot menu isn't displayed, and the computer boots into Windows 7 directly. 
How to fix this?

Comment: Did you install it using wubi? In which order did you install the OS's?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm newby, so I don't know wubi,,
Please explain what is wubi?,

Answer (score 3):

You most probably installed Windows last. This is a known issue where Windows overwrites the boot manager of Linux (called Grub2).

For information, read "[Recovering Ubuntu After Installing Linux](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows)".

Comment: should I install windows xp first on this partition to create MBR?,

Comment: if you install Windows then Ubuntu (Linux) and put the MBR on the first partition the system will then prompt you whether or not you want Windows or Ubuntu

Comment: hehe,, :D
Thanks 4 all whom help me,,
I have been succesful instal triple boot,,
Windows 7, Ubuntu, Kubuntu,,

Answer (score 0):

From the Ubuntu Community Wiki: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows  covers how to recover Ubuntu.  It might be a bit updated but should solve your problem.

Jonathan

Answer (score 0):

Install Windows first than Kubuntu.  Windows can mess with the bootloader when installing.

Comment: Grub also messes the Win bootloader, so it's not Windows hatin' on   the user, it's the fact that you must be careful when installing OSs

Comment: @UriHerrera Yes, but the Windows boot loader will not boot Ubuntu (at least not without some unusual manual configuration). The Ubuntu boot loader (GRUB2) is designed from the ground up to be able to boot to a variety of OSes including Windows, and Ubuntu usually configures it correctly when installed, so that you can always boot to either Ubuntu or Windows after installing Ubuntu.